# How to overcome ASCII sort order with regard to file names when using batch scripts?

Tags: javascript, sorting, vbscript, batch-file

I have a batch script which calls a jscript file (link below) to save excel workbook sheets as csv files.
http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2011/05/05/excel-batch-convert-xls-to-csv/

I then use batch scripting to merge these files together. However, if I encounter files that are named something like

> file1
>
> file2
>
> file10
>
> file11

then the files would be merged in the following order:

> file1
>
> file10
>
> file11
>
> file2

Presenting information in this order is not satisfactory.

Does anyone know of a method using batch or any other scripting language which would run on a typical Windows computer (e.g. JScript/VBscript) that would allow the files to be merged in 'human' order?

The method I was trying to implement was the following:
If a filename contains numbers determine how many digits the number contains and add zeros accordingly. E.g. `file1` would become `file001`.

This has failed miserably, repeatedly. Can this be done? Is there a better way?

Comment: You could use jscript to build a 2-dimensional array with `arr[0][0]=filename` and `arr[0][1]=/\d+/.exec(filename)`, then use a quicksort on the second column to put the files in order.  If you're still struggling with this tomorrow I'll show you some code.

Comment: Or if the files' timestamps are in order you could order the files by timestamp rather than by name.  That would certainly be the cleanest solution.

Comment: Hi rojo,

Thanks for the input. Unfortunately the timestamp may not be an indicator of file order. I'm just trying to set it up that if a number exists in a filename then it should be interpreted in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script adds leading zero's to the file name. Set the length of the file names as the number of zeros in the `%pre%` variable. File names with a greater length will not be processed. If a file name alredy exists, an error occurs. Look at the output and remove the `echo` command before `ren` if it is OK.

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "pre=0000000000" &rem max filename length-1

for /f "delims=:" %%i in ('^(@echo(%pre%^&@echo(^)^|findstr /o $') do set /a MinNameLength=%%i-3
for %%i in (*) do (
    set "fname=%%~ni"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=:" %%i in ('^(@echo(!fname!^&@echo(^)^|findstr /o $') do set /a fnamelen=%%i-3
    if !fnamelen! lss %MinNameLength% (
        set "fname=%pre%!fname!
        set "fname=!fname:~-%MinNameLength%!
        echo ren "%%~fi" "!fname!%%~xi"
    ) else (
    echo file name too long: %%~nxi
    )
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

I would recommend that you copy the files rather than rename them!

Comment: Thanks Endoro this looks like it fits the bill.

I didn’t realise you could put the zeros before the string characters in the file name and still have the same effect.

Results:

\00000file1.xlsx 
\00000file2.xlsx 
\00000file3.xlsx 
\00000file4.xlsx 
\00000file5.xlsx 
\00000file6.xlsx 
\00000file7.xlsx 
\00000file8.xlsx 
\00000file9.xlsx 
\0000file10.xlsx 
\0000file11.xlsx 
\0000file12.xlsx 

Your name will forever be immortalised in the comments in my final batch script.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The method with adding leading zeros should work - how exactly did it fail?

Also how these file names are generated? are they just sequential numbers, or they are arbitrary? If they are sequential, you do not have to count max number of digits, instead you can select a constant let us say 10 digits total. If you do 10, the algorithm will only break if you have more than 10 000 000 000 files to process, which I hope is not going to happen

Comment: Thanks for the response Frédéric
So the leading zeros method is sound?
I never implemented it properly because I’m still cutting my teeth with batch scripts and programming in general. I figured it was a good place to start learning the fundamentals.
I was working on renaming the files so it would be file1-file-10001 but that ran into the same problems. That’s when I realised I’d need to insert the zeros into the filename before the numbers.

I have no control over the files. The files come in as they are from client companies, and there’s no way of telling how they’ll be named.

Comment: That’s why the filename will need to be parsed dynamically looking for the first number, then adding as you say 10 zeros in front of it. It’s usually between 10 and 50 files but if more than 10 000 000 000 files come in, hey I’m just an intern, that sounds like a problem for the people who are getting paid. haha
Do you think this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to sort arrays of strings (like file names) in a case insensitive order, with numbers sorting by value instead of by character.
This one works very well for large arrays, and as well as most for smaller arrays.

```
Array.prototype.naturalSort= function naturalSort(index){
    var T= this, L= T.length, i, who, next,
    isi= typeof index== 'number',
    rx=/(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.\D+)|(\.$)/g;
    function nSort(aa, bb){
        var a= aa[0], b= bb[0], a1, b1, i= 0, n, L= a.length;
        while(i<L){
            if(!b[i]) return 1;
            a1= a[i];
            b1= b[i++];
            if(a1!== b1){
                n= a1-b1;
                if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
                return a1>b1? 1:-1;
            }
        }
        return b[i]? -1:0;
    }
    for(i= 0;i<L;i++){
        who= T[i];
        next= isi? T[i][index] || '':who;
        T[i]= [String(next).toLowerCase().match(rx), who];
    }
    T.sort(nSort);
    for(i= 0;i<L;i++){
        T[i]= T[i][1];
    }
}
```

You can rewrite it to get it out of the Array prototype and pass in the array, if you want.

Comment: Hi Kennebec, thanks for your response. It’s probably the most appropriate way to go about solving the problem but it’s a little over my head right now. I’m certain more advanced users than I will make great use of your code when they stumble across this page. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If all the files have the same naming scheme, i.e. from "file1" to "file999", then is very easy (and fast!) to achieve such rename. The Batch file below take two arguments: the fixed part of the file name and the number of digits you want in the new names. For example `renumber.bat file 4` results in new names like "file0001", "file0002"... to "file0999".

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("%~1*.*") do (
   set "name=%%~Na"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set number=0000000000!name:%~1=!
   ECHO ren "%%a" "%~1!number:~-%2!%%~Xa"
   endlocal
)
```

**EDIT**: *Optional method added*

On the other hand, the Batch file below insert leading zeros in the names as Endoro suggested in his answer. In this case, put the *total lenght* of the new names in the first parameter; original longer names will not be processed.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set name=0000000000000000%%a
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set newName=!name:~-%1!
   if "!newName:~0,1!" equ "0" ECHO ren "%%a" "!newName!"
   endlocal
)
```

Comment: Hi Aacini, thanks for the input. Could you help me troubleshoot an issue? When I run this file I’m getting “A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found”. I’m currently working with files called PPR1 PPR2 etc. I tried working with test files called file 1, file 2 etc. but these did not rename either. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: 1. If last file names have N digits, use N+1 digits in the new names (as I shown in my answer) OR insert `if not exist "%~1!number:~-%2!%%~Xa"` before the `ren` command if you want to preserve the same number of digits. 2. If the fixed part of the file names have spaces, then give they: `rename "file " 4`

Comment: @user2263364: Did you solved your concerns? Do my method correctly works?

Comment: thanks again for your response. Turns out I didn't have to solve this problem in batch. The batch calls a jscript file and I changed that file to name the files putting the leading zeros in.