# how can I write DOS batch file to rename from 1.jpg to 0001.jpg?

Tags: batch-file, dos

how can I write DOS batch file to rename multiple files in any subdirectory from

```
1.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
```

it's not logically arrange and I want it to

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
```

which put 000 in front of it as>>

```
0001.jpg
0002.jpg
0003.jpg
0004.jpg....
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,999) DO (
SET newname=000%%i
SET newname=!newname:~-4!
IF EXIST %%i.jpg ECHO REN %%i.jpg !newname!.jpg
)
```

Since your names don't include any non-alphameric character, it's a reasonably simple task.

change to the required subdirecory, take the numbers 1..999 in a loop, prefix with '000' then get the last 4 characters and do your rename.

I've included an `ECHO` so the operation is simply reported. remove the `ECHO` keyword to execute the rename.

The `IF EXIST` gate stops attempted renamng if the original name doesn't exist (which would generate an ugly error message) and this could be gated again if required to prevent attempted renaming if the new filename already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set name=0000%%a
   if not exist !name:~-8! ECHO ren %%a !name:~-8!
)
```

You may review a more general method here: [How to overcome ASCII sort order with regard to file names when using batch scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911727/how-to-overcome-ascii-sort-order-with-regard-to-file-names-when-using-batch-scri/15916074#15916074) when the file names may have a fixed part before the digits.

Comment: Thank to you too , Aacini :D